# Button enable and disable on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, togglebutton, disabled-input

So I have this link to press

```
<a href="link" target="_blank">
    <div class="well">
        <span> blabla </span>
    </div>
</a>
```

and this button code in a page

```
<button  type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg" disabled="disabled"> Blabla </button>
```

And as you can see the button is disabled for now. How can I make that when I press that link the button to be enabled again? sorry for my bad English..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Try this generalized function for toggleDisabled

```js
//Generalized function to make element toggleDisabled.
(function($) {
    $.fn.toggleDisabled = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            this.disabled = !this.disabled;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
//Code to use toggleDisabled
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
      $("button[type='submit']").toggleDisabled();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="link" target="_blank">
    <div class="well">
        <span> blabla </span>
    <div>
</a> 
<br/>      
<button  type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg" disabled="disabled"> Blabla </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code will be useful

```
document.getElementById('click').onclick = function(event){
// on click prevent the default behavior
event.preventDefault();
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary')[0].disabled = false;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hpnfjsyu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an `id` property to your button and link so they are easier to access with Javascript. Let's say you assign `id="myButton"` to the button and `id="myLink"` to the anchor tag:

```
$('#myLink').on('click', function() {
   $('#myButton').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    $("button[type='submit']").removeAttr('disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <a href="link" target="_blank"><div class="well">
    <span> blabla </span>
    <div></a>
   
<button  type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg" disabled="disabled"> Blabla </button>
```